# Ler Arquivo PDF ou TXT no java

Tags: java

Olá. Estou fazendo um trabalho do curso em que tenho que pegar um arquivo PDF ou o TXT que o professor passou, e encriptar ele pelos algoritmos de cifra de Cesar, playfrai e transposição. Gostaria de saber como faço para meu algoritmo ler esse arquivo ou em PDF ou o TXT e encriptar no formato pedido, pois toda vez que passo muito texto grande ele quebra.

Segue um dos algoritmos que pretendo usar para realizar a atividades. Estou apto a sugestões.

```
public static class CaesarCipher
{
    public static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    public static String encrypt(String plainText, int shiftKey)
    {
        plainText = plainText.toLowerCase();
        String cipherText = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++)
        {
            int charPosition = ALPHABET.indexOf(plainText.charAt(i));
            int keyVal = (shiftKey + charPosition) % 26;
            char replaceVal = ALPHABET.charAt(keyVal);
            cipherText += replaceVal;
        }
        return cipherText;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String cipherText, int shiftKey)
    {
        cipherText = cipherText.toLowerCase();
        String plainText = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < cipherText.length(); i++)
        {
            int charPosition = ALPHABET.indexOf(cipherText.charAt(i));
            int keyVal = (charPosition - shiftKey) % 26;
            if (keyVal < 0)
            {
                keyVal = ALPHABET.length() + keyVal;
            }
            char replaceVal = ALPHABET.charAt(keyVal);
            plainText += replaceVal;
        }
        return plainText;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the String for Encryption: ");
        String message = new String();
        message = sc.next();
        System.out.println(encrypt(message, 3));
        System.out.println(decrypt(encrypt(message, 3), 3));
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: editei e coloquei , amigo ele funciona mais quando seleciono uma grande parte do texto ele empaca gostaria de ler o arquivo e realizar as operações.

Comment: Sim amigo ! Gostaria de saber como faço para implementar isso no código . Se houver um forma de ler o arquivo e praticar oque o algoritmo faz . Se vc tiver outra sugestão aceito . Obrigado pela atenção.